# MVC file upload UnauthorizedAccessException

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010

I have this code:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Photograph photo, HttpPostedFileBase image)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (image != null)
            {
                byte[] imageData = new byte[image.ContentLength];
                image.InputStream.Read(imageData, 0, image.ContentLength);
                System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/Content/Images"), imageData);
            }

            repository.SavePhotograph(photo);
            TempData["message"] = string.Format("{0} has been saved", photo.Name);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        else
        {
            return View(photo);
        }
    }
```

It is meant to take the photo uploaded from a form and save it in the server (local server). I've given the folder "Visual Studio 2010" where all the projects are kept NETWORK SERVICE user permissions and IIS_IUSRS group permissions. I'm also running visual studio as administrator.

For some reason it still won't let me save the file to that location. The location is within the project folder under {Project_Name\Content\Images}. How do I get it to save the file there?

Thanks,

Comment: Are you running this via Visual Studio in debug mode or deployed to IIS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it was giving me that error is because the method:

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes()
```

Takes, the path of the FILE and the data.

I was passing a folder

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/Content/Images"), imageData);
```

I should have been passing a file:

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(String.Format("{0}{1}", HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/Content/Images"), image.FileName), imageData);
```

Now I'm getting an error with my repository so I'm looking into that :) I love coding so much  .... ;)

Answer (score 0):

> For some reason it still won't let me save the file to that location.

Are you getting any errors ? if yes please post full errors here.

**Case I :** If you are using Visual Studio to run your MVC app, make sure you run visual studio using the '**Run as Administrator**' Option.

**Case II:** If you are running your MVC app on IIS. Goto the folder where the images are being saved. That is grant 'IIS_IUSRS' user <s>Full control</s> 'modify' rights.

Comment: I would recommend in Case II that IIS_IUSRS are granted 'modify' rights and not full control.  No reason for IIS to have the ability to set permissions/take ownership of files/etc.  Just 2 cents...

Comment: @Tommy ya I realize that now, have made the change. Thanks

Comment: I have got visual studio running as Administrator in the way you have described there. If IIS_IUSRS has full control anyway it should still work. The error is UnauthorizedAccessException.

Comment: Are you running this via Visual Studio in debug mode or deployed to IIS?

Answer (score 0):

RE: the line with "System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes"... are you trying to save to the directory? Where does it selected a filename for the uploaded file?